# End the jQuery function when its recalled

Tags: jquery

i build a jQuery function here http://jsfiddle.net/JuW3B/3/

i want this function stop animating and completes it's animation when it's recalled by another action before the first animation completed,

so, when it's called like this

```
$('.a').pushUp();
```

and then another action which call to this function before the first function completing it's animation

```
$('.b').pushUp();
```

i want to forcedly ended the first function before the second function begin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the animation for `$('.a')` you can simply call `$('.a').stop(true, true);` The second boolean will determine whether the animation goes straight to the end or not.

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

I don't know what exactly you want to do, but I just tested it on your fiddle and it stops AAA from animating : http://jsfiddle.net/JuW3B/7/

BTW, I changed the `pushUp` value to `10000` to see it a little slower.

Regards.